# Definition of solution of a differential equation and how do we know we obtained a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $y^{'}=f(x,y(x)) \implies y(x)=g(x)$ for some $g$. Where the implication follows by some suitable operations.

Is then $g$ a solution to the differential equation by defult?

The converse is

$y(x)=g(x) \implies y^{'}=f(x,y(x))$, which looks like the definition of a solution.

Since solution to a DE is defined to be any $g$ satisfying the equation as far as I understand.

The reason I ask is that it is not always trival to go backwards if one just do some calculations on say a seperable first order equation.

Is the only way to know that we obtined a solution to plug it in? Or is there some other way of knowing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given the DE $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$, then your task is to find *all* functions $g(x)$ such that $y(x)=g(x)$ is a solution. Such functions are not unique, but they all verify the DE.

**Example:**

$$y'(x)=y(x)$$ is solved by $$y(x)=Ce^x$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. As you can check, for any $C$, $$(Ce^x)'=Ce^x.$$

---

If you are given a function $g(x)$, it is possible to find many DE that it fulfills. And every such equation has a family of solutions.

**Example:**

The function $$y(x)=e^x$$ is a solution of the DE $$y'(x)=e^x.$$ The other solutions of this equation are $$y(x)=e^x+C.$$

It is also a solution of

$$y'(x)=\frac{e^{2x}}{y(x)}$$ and other solutions are

$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{{e^{2x}+C}}.$$

---

If you are given a single solution $g(x)$, you cannot retrieve $f$. For this, you need to know the whole family of functions.

**Example:**

From $$y(x)=Ce^x$$ you draw $$y'(x)=Ce^x=y(x)$$ and $$y'(x)=y(x)$$ is the only DE you obtain where $C$ has been eliminated.

Comment: If one looks at the definiton of a solution it says that a solution is any $g$ such that $g$ sasify the equation similar to your second example. I.e $y=g \implies g^{'}=f(x,g)$. On the other hand let us start with $f$ ( as in your first example) then we might get that $y=h$ for some explixit $h$. But this only says that $y^{'}=f(x,y)$ implies that $y=h$. Which is the convese of the first implication, so how do we know that $h$ is a solution without trying it?

Comment: @mathgeeek: by solving the equation.

Comment: but I dont see how that gives $y(x)=g(x) \implies y^{'}=f(x,y(x))$ i.e that $g$ is a soltuion. I only see that solving the equation gives $y^{'}=f(x,y(x)) \implies y(x)=g(x)$

Comment: If one preforms some "non-bijective" operation then we cant go back right?

Comment: @mathgeeek: I answered that in my post.

Comment: Ok ill reread it in a while.

Comment: But I dont even see why my first implication gives that g is a solution ignoring the uniqueness.

Comment: @mathgeeek: sorry to say but your first implication is kind of silly. It says if $y$ fulfills this DE, then $y$ is a function.

Comment: well it is of an explicit form up to some parameter possibly. This is what one gets by applying integrating factor for instance

Comment: @mathgeeek: all you say is "$y$ is a function".

Comment: I am sorry but how do I know that it is a solution then? Because this is how one finds them often. This is what bothers me

Comment: I am starting to think that the only way of knowing that one has got a solution by manipulating the equation is by plugging it in, is this correct? Or is there some other way?

Comment: @mathgeeek: no, the steps of the resolution lead you to guaranteed solutions.

Comment: So we only loose implications the way back to the extent that the operations fail to be bijective?

Comment: @mathgeeek: sorry again, but this is in my answer.

Comment: Yea it is a little bit to implicit for me to feel confident about it. I can see it tho. Thanks for the answer and comments.